# Coverting two uint32_varible in in one Uint8

Tags: c, pointers, bit-shift

I have a question with converting two uint32 variables and pass it as one uin8 variable. I am not sure how to exactly proceed with it ? or dont know even if it is possible.
I want it in litte endian approach.
Also is it possible to pass the array values as a one variable as unint8_t* as i need to send the value to the function

func(uint8_t *result);

example

```
uint32_t var1 = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
uint32_t var2 = 9 A B C D E F 0
```

result

```
*uint8_t= 12 34 56 78 9A BC DE F0
```

I tried this approach but not sure how to use it with two uint_32 variables

```
uint32_t value;
uint8_t *result[4];

result[0] = (value & 0x000000ff);
result[1] = (value & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
result[2] = (value & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
result[3] = (value & 0xff000000) >> 24;

func(uint8_t *result);
```

I am getting *** stack smashing detected ***: terminated

Comment: `result` shouldn't be an array of pointers, it should be an array of `uint8_t`.

Comment: It appears you may want to copy the values or bits in two `uint32_t` objects into an array of `uint8_t` objects, not into one `uint8_t`. (`uint32_t` and `uint8_t` are standard C types; if you are working with something that defines `uint32` and `uin8` or `uint8`, those are likely equivalent, but the standard types should generally be preferred.) The way into which bits from `uint32_t` objects ought to be copied into an array of `uint8_t` depends on the reasons for doing it. For example, one reason might be preparing data for network transmission…

Comment: For some purposes, the bytes need to go into the array “big end” (most significant bytes) first. For other purposes, the native order of the C implementation might be desired. In other contexts, maybe some sort of interleaving is desired, due to the origins of the `uint32_t` values. So you need to edit the question to provide full context or specifications for what the desired results are.

Comment: Hello @EricPostpischil I am using this for communication over controller area network the var1 and var2 are data high and low bits, I need to send to my application which recieves as uint_8 *

Comment: Does the sending system use big-endian or little-endian ordering of bytes in integers? Does the receiving application expect big-endian or little-endian?

Comment: @user20156410 Did you want result "12 34 56 **7**8 9A BC DE F0" and not "12 34 56 **9**8 9A BC DE F0" as posted?

Comment: Posted code would not result in "*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated".  Best to post a [MCVE].

Comment: `uint32_t var1 = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8` is unclear.  Did you mean `uint32_t var1 = 0x12345678;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the main error that you get is due to definingthe result vector as pointer array but later writing them with values. this is constructed at heap. what you want is to define an array of uint_8 of size 4 or 8 which store values corresponding to uint32_t.

since you are using uC, they could have different bytes order to represent words or datas (like int32 , int64 , etc). since you gave the example that you expect, and I am runnign the code on LSB or little endian pc (x86, arm, 64 etc ) then I have to parse it as follow. but in uC if it is Big endian (MSB first) then parse in reverse.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>

uint32_t var1 = 0x12345678;
uint32_t var2 = 0x9ABCDEF0;


void to_uint8_t(uint32_t value, uint8_t* result){
    for(uint16_t i = 0; i< 4;i++)
        result[3 - i] = (value >> (i * 8))& 0xff; /* little endian*/
        // result[i] = (value >> (i * 8))& 0xff; /* big endian*/
}

int main(){
    uint8_t result[8];
    
    to_uint8_t(var1, result);
    to_uint8_t(var2, result + 4);
    
    for(uint16_t i =0; i< 8;i++)
       printf("%x ", result[i]);
    printf("\n");    
}
```

output:

```
12 34 56 78 9a bc de f0
```

Comment: You provided code for big-endiand and little-endian byte order. If they want native byte order, they can simply use `memcpy`.

Comment: Code-only answers are not recommended -- please provide explanation for what you have done

Comment: @ikegami it was for demonstration to follow the original way of writing in the question. surely in one of them could be replaced by memcpy.

Comment: @M.M thanks for feedback, sure, you are right. I was mostly thinking then based on the question , since it has minimal change could be easily followed, however i ll add description

Comment: Re "*surely in one of them could be replaced by memcpy*", That would not be equivalent, no, unless you sacrifice portability. There are three byte orders: native, little-endian and big-endian. `memcpy` will produce native. You provided the way of getting the other two.

Comment: Curious, why `uint16_t` in `for(uint16_t i =0; i< 8;i++)`?

Comment: @ikegami no specific reasons , it is only for print and probably better to be either int or uint8_t since it is only 8, you have specific comment or recommendation?